# EOle error on calling HTML file in a TWebBrowser Delphi

Tags: delphi, ole, twebbrowser

I am actually getting a huge problem.
In fact, my program is working well on my computer but when i do a setup file in order to install on other computer, and when i install it, it failed.

In my program i got procedures calling an index.html file i use and load in my TWebBrowser.
Then, on other computers i got the following error : EOleException, Error 80020101.

Thanks for all help
Gwenael

Comment: Do the Internet Explorer versions differ across the different computers? Did you try to simplify the HTML page to locate the error (meaning: remove stuff until the error goes away)? Related question: does your page contain frames/iframes?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about Javascript. If you use JS in Index.html file, may be the javascript method can't be found. (I'm not sure just guessing)

Comment: Perhaps, but how can it be found on my computer and not on customers computer ??? that's the problem i think

Comment: 80020101 could be [SCRIPT_E_REPORTED](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247784). Also see comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5684736/11480).